# Initializing Doctrine is so slow

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

here is some code:

```
  $paths = array(APP_LIBS.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Doctrine'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Entity');

  // the connection configuration
  $dbParams = array(
    'dbname' => $di->get('config')->database->dbname,
    'user' => $di->get('config')->database->username,
    'password' => $di->get('config')->database->password,
    'host' => $di->get('config')->database->host,
    'port' => (int)$di->get('config')->database->port,
    'charset'  => 'UTF8',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'
  );

  $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $di->get('env')->isDebugActive(), APP_PATH_CACHE_DOCTRINE, null, false);

  $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($di->get('env')->isDev());

  $driverChain = new Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain();

  $cachedAnnotationReader = $config->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getReader();
  \Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM($driverChain, $cachedAnnotationReader);

  $driverChain->addDriver($config->getMetadataDriverImpl(), "Doctrine\Entity");

  $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverChain);
  if ((bool)$di->get('config')->application->sqlLog)
  {
    $config->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\Logger\FileSQLLogger());
  }
  $config->addCustomNumericFunction('RAND', 'Doctrine\Custom\Functions\Rand');
  $config->addCustomStringFunction('REGEXP', 'Doctrine\Custom\Functions\Regexp');
  $config->addCustomStringFunction('CONCAT_WS', 'Doctrine\Custom\Functions\ConcatWs');

  // create event manager and hook preferred extension listeners
  $evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();

  // gedmo extension listeners, remove which are not used

  // sluggable
  $sluggableListener = new Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener;
  // you should set the used annotation reader to listener, to avoid creating new one for mapping drivers
  $sluggableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($sluggableListener);

  // tree
  $treeListener = new Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener;
  $treeListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($treeListener);

  // loggable, not used in example
  $loggableListener = new Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener;
  $loggableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($loggableListener);

  // timestampable
  $timestampableListener = new Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener;
  $timestampableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($timestampableListener);

  // translatable
  $translatableListener = new Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener;
  // current translation locale should be set from session or hook later into the listener
  // most important, before entity manager is flushed
  $translatableListener->setTranslatableLocale('en');
  $translatableListener->setDefaultLocale('en');
  $translatableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($translatableListener);

  // sortable, not used in example
  $sortableListener = new Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener;
  $sortableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
  $evm->addEventSubscriber($sortableListener);

  // mysql set names UTF-8 if required
  $evm->addEventSubscriber(new Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\MysqlSessionInit());

  $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config, $evm);

  $platform = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();

  \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('json', '\Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType');
  $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping("json", 'json');
  $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

this is very slow, about 2 seconds. Any chance to make it faster

Answer (score 2):

You should add `Metadata caching` to config.

```
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache());
```

docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#metadata-cache-recommended

Comment: almost, but I cant install APC on Debian

Comment: Then use one od other supported drivers (redis/memcache(d)/xcache) for details check linked docs.

Comment: right, I made it with "redis". It didnt even became any faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xhprof` http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php php extensions for analyses your application and get slow code function or part code. After profiling you can get graphic call function and time this graphic like this 
[image]